# Replace value of NA based on the mean of nearest groupings of columns in a table

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

My objective is to replace NAs with nearest groupings of variables. For instance, let's say there are four variables `A`, `B` , `C` and `Num`. `Num` is numerical variable, while `A`, `B` and `C` are categorical. Now if the value of `Num` is missing for say, `A` = Alpha, `B` = Beta and `C` = Theta, then I would like to look for other observations for this combination, calculate their mean and replace NA.

If such combination doesn't exist, I would look for observations with combinations of  `A` = Alpha and `B` = Beta (hence, the term "nearest groupings"), calculate their mean and substitute it.

If such combination doesn't exist, I would look for all observations classified as `A` = Alpha, calculate their mean and substitute it.

If this is the only observation, then we will replace it with 0. I have created such scenarios in the test file I am posting herewith.

While my code works well, it's very procedural. I have transitioned from doing C/C++ programming and I am still not used to R's vectorized methods. Hence, I am looking for a method that is:

a) cleaner (no `for` loops please; less memory and faster). While writing the code, I realized that I am not fully utilizing the power of R programming.

b) easy to understand.

I have added comments in sample output below just for reference.

**Input Data:**

```
dput(DFile)
structure(list(Region_SL = c("G1", "G1", "G1", "G1", "G2", "G2", 
"G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G5", "G5", "G5", "G5", "G5", "G6"), 
    Country_SV = c("United States", "United States", "United States", 
    "United States", "United States", "United States", "United States", 
    NA, NA, NA, "Europe", "UK", "France", "Europe", "Europe", 
    "Australia"), Product_BU = c("Laptop", "Laptop", "Laptop", 
    "Laptop", "Laptop", "Laptop", "Laptop", NA, NA, NA, "Pencil", 
    "Power Cord", "Laptop", "Keyboard", "Mouse", "Motherboard"
    ), Prob_model3 = c(0, 79647405.9878251, 282615405.328728, 
    NA, NA, 363419594.065383, 0, 72870592.8458704, 260045174.088548, 
    369512727.253779, NA, 234, NA, 5, 10, NA)), .Names = c("Region_SL", 
"Country_SV", "Product_BU", "Prob_model3"), row.names = c(NA, 
16L), class = "data.frame")
```

**Expected Output:**
Please note that comments are just for reference. That column isn't required.

```
dput(Output)
structure(list(Region_SL = c("G1", "G1", "G1", "G1", "G2", "G2", 
"G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G5", "G5", "G5", "G5", "G5", "G6"), 
    Country_SV = c("United States", "United States", "United States", 
    "United States", "United States", "United States", "United States", 
    "United States", "United States", "United States", "Europe", 
    "UK", "France", "Europe", "Europe", "Australia"), Product_BU = c("Laptop", 
    "Laptop", "Laptop", "Laptop", "Laptop", "Laptop", "Laptop", 
    "Laptop", "Laptop", "Laptop", "Pencil", "Power Cord", "Laptop", 
    "Keyboard", "Mouse", "Motherboard"), Prob_model3 = c(0, 79647405.9878251, 
    282615405.328728, 120754270.438851, 363419594.065383, 363419594.065383, 
    0, 72870592.8458704, 260045174.088548, 369512727.253779, 
    7.5, 234, 83, 5, 10, 0), Comment = c(NA, NA, NA, "Grouped on G1, Laptop, US; Average of rows 1 to 3", 
    "Grouped on G2, US, Laptop; Average is the only value in row 6", 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "Group of G5, Europe and Pencil are unique; G5 and Europe exist. Average of row 14 and 15", 
    NA, "Group of G5, France and Laptop is unique; Group of G5 and France is unique as well; Use group of G5 and take average of row 12, 14, 15", 
    NA, NA, "Unique. Substitute 0")), .Names = c("Region_SL", 
"Country_SV", "Product_BU", "Prob_model3", "Comment"), row.names = c(NA, 
16L), class = "data.frame")
```

Here's my code: (The code works well, and the expected output is `b`. `b` is nothing but `Output` posted above without the comments.

```
DFile_New <-DFile
DFile_New<-DFile_New %>% 
  arrange(Region_SL, Country_SV,Product_BU) 

#replace categorical variable with the combination above or below the row to complete cases.
DFile_New[,1:3]<-  zoo::na.locf(DFile_New[,1:3])

#Create look-up table for means, for each type of combination.
Lookup1<- DFile_New %>%
  dplyr::group_by(Region_SL, Country_SV, Product_BU) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(count=n(),Mean_prob = mean(Prob_model3,na.rm = TRUE)) 

Lookup2<-DFile_New %>%
  dplyr::group_by(Region_SL, Country_SV) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(count=n(),Mean_prob = mean(Prob_model3,na.rm = TRUE)) 

Lookup3<-DFile_New %>%
  dplyr::group_by(Region_SL) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(count=n(),Mean_prob = mean(Prob_model3,na.rm = TRUE)) 

Lookup_Table<-dplyr::bind_rows(Lookup1,Lookup2,Lookup3)

#Get rid of those rows with count = 1
Lookup_Table<-Lookup_Table[!Lookup_Table$count==1,]
colnames(Lookup_Table)[5]<-"Prob_model3"

#Look for combinations based on Region, Country and Product
b<-DFile_New %>%
  dplyr::left_join(Lookup_Table,by=c("Region_SL", "Country_SV", "Product_BU"))
b$Prob_model3 <- coalesce(b$Prob_model3.x,b$Prob_model3.y)
#Drop the two columns
b$Prob_model3.x<-NULL
b$Prob_model3.y<-NULL
b$count<-NULL
b<-b[!(is.na(b$Country_SV)&is.na(b$Product_BU)),]


c<-b[is.na(b$Prob_model3),] %>%
  dplyr::left_join(Lookup_Table[is.na(Lookup_Table$Product_BU) & !is.na(Lookup_Table$Country_SV),],by=c("Region_SL", "Country_SV")) %>%
    dplyr::mutate(Prob_model3 = coalesce(Prob_model3.x,Prob_model3.y)) %>%
    dplyr::select(Region_SL:Product_BU.x, Prob_model3)
colnames(c)[3]<-"Product_BU"
colnames(c)[4]<-"Prob_model3"

b<-rbind(b,c)
b%>% unite(Col,Region_SL:Product_BU,sep=".")
c<-b
b<-b[complete.cases(b[4]),]

#Look for combinations based on Region, and Country     
c<-c[is.na(c$Prob_model3),] %>%
  dplyr::left_join(Lookup_Table[is.na(Lookup_Table$Product_BU) & is.na(Lookup_Table$Country_SV),],by=c("Region_SL")) %>%
  dplyr::filter(!is.na(Prob_model3.y)) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(Prob_model3.1 = coalesce(Prob_model3.x,Prob_model3.y)) %>%
  dplyr::select(Region_SL:Product_BU.x, Prob_model3.1) %>%
  unique(.)
colnames(c)[3]<-"Product_BU"
colnames(c)[2]<-"Country_SV"

#Look for combinations based on Region     
b<-b%>% 
  full_join(c) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(Prob_model3.2 = coalesce(Prob_model3,Prob_model3.1)) %>%
  dplyr::select(Region_SL:Product_BU,Prob_model3.2)
colnames(b)[4]<-"Prob_model3"

#Are there any unique observations left?
b<-rbind(b,anti_join(DFile_New,b,by=c("Region_SL", "Country_SV", "Product_BU")))
b[is.na(b$Prob_model3),"Prob_model3"]<-0
```

I'm relatively new to the world of R programming. I'd sincerely appreciate any help.
I'm preferably looking for advanced solution--lapply/dplyr/tidyr, anything is fine, so long as it isn't so complicated as mine.

---

My sessionInfo:

```
R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] grDevices datasets  stats     graphics  grid      tcltk     utils     methods   base    

$otherPkgs
 [1] "bit"               "bit64"             "boot"              "car"               "compare"          
 [6] "corrgram"          "corrplot"          "cowplot"           "debug"             "directlabels"     
[11] "dplyr"             "foreign"           "Formula"           "ggplot2"           "ggthemes"         
[16] "gmodels"           "hexbin"            "Hmisc"             "installr"          "knitr"            
[21] "lattice"           "lubridate"         "magrittr"          "maps"              "openxlsx"         
[26] "pastecs"           "plotly"            "plyr"              "psych"             "purrr"            
[31] "R2HTML"            "readr"             "readstata13"       "reshape2"          "ResourceSelection"
[36] "rJava"             "rmarkdown"         "sm"                "stringr"           "survival"         
[41] "tables"            "tibble"            "tidyr"             "tidyverse"         "tufte"            
[46] "tufterhandout"     "vcd"               "xlsxjars"          "xts"               "zoo"              

$loadedOnly
 [1] "acepack"      "assertthat"   "backports"    "base64enc"    "bitops"       "broom"        "caTools"     
 [8] "checkmate"    "class"        "cluster"      "codetools"    "colorspace"   "data.table"   "DBI"         
[15] "dendextend"   "DEoptimR"     "digest"       "diptest"      "evaluate"     "flexmix"      "foreach"     
[22] "fpc"          "gclus"        "gdata"        "gplots"       "gridExtra"    "gtable"       "gtools"      
[29] "haven"        "hms"          "htmlTable"    "htmltools"    "htmlwidgets"  "httr"         "iterators"   
[36] "jsonlite"     "kernlab"      "KernSmooth"   "latticeExtra" "lazyeval"     "lme4"         "lmtest"      
[43] "MASS"         "Matrix"       "MatrixModels" "mclust"       "mgcv"         "minqa"        "mnormt"      
[50] "modelr"       "modeltools"   "munsell"      "mvbutils"     "mvtnorm"      "nlme"         "nloptr"      
[57] "nnet"         "parallel"     "pbkrtest"     "prabclus"     "quadprog"     "quantreg"     "R6"          
[64] "RColorBrewer" "Rcpp"         "readxl"       "registry"     "robustbase"   "rpart"        "rprojroot"   
[71] "rvest"        "scales"       "seriation"    "SparseM"      "splines"      "stats4"       "stringi"     
[78] "tools"        "trimcluster"  "TSP"          "viridisLite"  "whisker"      "xml2"
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a two-step solution using `dplyr` tools:

1. Create columns that represent "lookups" for specific type of averaging;
2. Replace `NA`s in consecutive fashion.

Here is the code:

```
library(dplyr)

df_1 <- df %>%
  group_by(Region_SL) %>%
  summarise(lookup_1 = mean(Prob_model3, na.rm=TRUE))
df_2 <- df %>%
  group_by(Region_SL, Country_SV) %>%
  summarise(lookup_2 = mean(Prob_model3, na.rm=TRUE))
df_3 <- df %>%
  group_by(Region_SL, Country_SV, Product_BU) %>%
  summarise(lookup_3 = mean(Prob_model3, na.rm=TRUE))

df_new <- df %>%
  left_join(df_3, by = c("Region_SL", "Country_SV", "Product_BU")) %>%
  left_join(df_2, by = c("Region_SL", "Country_SV")) %>%
  left_join(df_1, by = c("Region_SL")) %>%
  mutate(modProb_model3 = coalesce(x=Prob_model3,
                                   lookup_3, lookup_2, lookup_1,
                                   0)) %>%
  select(Region_SL, Country_SV, Product_BU, Prob_model3=modProb_model3)
```

Here `df` is the input data frame. `df_1`, `df_2` and `df_3` are data frames with certain averaging information (index represents the number of categorical variables for grouping).

After consecutive left joins new variable `modProb_model3` is created with `coalesce` function: it finds the first non-missing value at each position.

**Edit**

I think that solution above is the most effective for a particular problem. If, for example, there are at least 10 possible groupings to consider in NA replacing then some automation will be better. This automation can be as follows (using packages `tidyverse` and `lazyeval`):

```
library(tidyverse)

value_name <- "Prob_model3"
max_group_vars <- c("Region_SL", "Country_SV", "Product_BU")
n_group_vars <- length(max_group_vars)
lookup_vars_list <- c(x = value_name, paste0("lookup_", n_group_vars:1)) %>%
  as.list()

get_lookup_table <- function(.data,
                             group_vars,
                             value_name = "Prob_model3",
                             lookup_index = 1) {
  summarise_data <- (~ mean(val, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
    lazyeval::interp(val = as.name(value_name)) %>%
    list() %>%
    setNames(paste0("lookup_", lookup_index))
  .data %>%
    group_by_(.dots = as.list(group_vars)) %>%
    summarise_(.dots = summarise_data)
}

df_new_1 <- c(
  list(df),
  map(n_group_vars:1, function(lookup_index) {
    get_lookup_table(.data = df,
                     group_vars = max_group_vars[1:lookup_index],
                     value_name = value_name,
                     lookup_index = lookup_index)
  })
) %>%
  reduce(left_join) %>%
  mutate(modValue = select_(., .dots = lookup_vars_list) %>%
           as.list() %>%
           c(0) %>%
           do.call(what = coalesce)) %>%
  select(-matches(match = paste0("^lookup_[0-9]+$|", value_name))) %>%
  rename_(.dots = setNames(list("modValue"), value_name))
```

Basically algorithm is the same but code is more general: it replaces `NA` values in column with name `value_name` based on its averages in groups defined by decreasing set of column names (starting with the set stored in `max_group_vars`). Code uses standard evaluation of `dplyr` heavily (see https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/nse.html). Here are some explanations:

1. `get_lookup_table` creates lookup table for specified grouping variables. The lookup column has unique name `lookup_i` where `i` - specified index of lookup table;
2. Consecutive left joins are done with `reduce` function which consecutively applies a function with two arguments (here `left_join` with `x` and `y`) to its previous call and a new value. For example: f1=f(x1, x2) --> f2=f(f1, x3) and so on. **Note** Left joins are done correctly without specifying `by` argument because lookup tables are created in a way that "natural join" is correct. Also there will be `dplyr` warnings about its guessing of joining columns;
3. `modValue` is created with function `do.call` and created preliminary  list of arguments for `coalesce`;
4. The last two elements in the pipe: selects appropriate columns with use of regular expression and then renames `modValue` to the desired `value_name`.

Comment: Terrific response. Do you think we could shorten the generation of lookup tables? I believe our code has a bit of redundancy in that we are writing a lot of repetitive stuff. What do you think?

Comment: Edited the answer. But I think there are not so many situations in which this complicated approach will be effective (aside from learning techniques involved :) ).

Comment: Thanks so much. I'm getting the following error: `Error in UseMethod("group_by_") :  no applicable method for 'group_by_' applied to an object of class "function"`. I did traceback and found that there is an issue with `11.dplyr::group_by_`.... Traceback: `11. dplyr::group_by_... 10. function_list[[i]](value)  9. freduce(value, `_function_list`) 8. `_fseq`(`_lhs`) 7. eval(expr, envir, ...) 
6. eval(quote(`_fseq`(`_lhs`)), env, env)  5. withVisible(eval(quote...
4. .data %>% dplyr::group_by_....3. get_lookup_table 2..f(.x[[i]], ...) 1. 
purrr::map` I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't reproduce your error. The possible issues of this behaviour are:

1. Not installed package `lazyeval`;
2. Not properly copied code into your console.

Comment: Thanks again for your help. I am posting sessionInfo(). Do you think it might help? I have also tried copy-pasting your code a multiple times, but the problem persists.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't see objective possible reason why this code throws an error in your R session.